# Вывод данных из бд по выбранному пунтку списка

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

Сделал вывод данных из бд на страницу, но все записи идут по очереди списком.
Как сделать вывод например при выборе id из бд?

```
<?php
        $zayav = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `applications`");
        $zayav = mysqli_fetch_all($zayav);
        foreach ($zayav as $zayav) {
            ?>
                    Имя: <?= $zayav[16] ?><br>
                    Фамилия: <?= $zayav[15] ?><br>
          Отчество: <?= $zayav[17] ?><br>
          Дата рождения: <?= $zayav[18] ?><br>
          Номер паспорта: <?= $zayav[19] ?>; Серия: <?= $zayav[20] ?><br>
          Место рождения: <?= $zayav[21] ?>, <?= $zayav[22] ?> <?= $zayav[23] ?><br>
          Категория ТС: <?= $zayav[2] ?><br>
          Тип ТС: <?= $zayav[3] ?>; Мощность: <?= $zayav[4] ?> Л.С<br>
          Марка: <?= $zayav[6] ?>; Модель: <?= $zayav[7] ?>; Год выпуска: <?= $zayav[8] ?><br>
          Цель использования: <?= $zayav[5] ?><br>
          Индефикатор ТС: <?= $zayav[9] ?>; Гос. номер: <?= $zayav[10] ?><br>
          Номер паспорта ТС: <?= $zayav[11] ?>; Серия ТС: <?= $zayav[12] ?><br>
          Дата выдачи: <?= $zayav[13] ?><br>
          Поставлено на учет: <?= $zayav[14] ?>; Наличие доп.лиц <?= $zayav[24] ?><br>

            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

*Код вывода из бд*

Comment: Это ```$zayav``` на победу, у вас пример немного кривой....

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 - передавать в запрос id нужной Вам записи

```
<? 
$zayav = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE `Ваш столбец в котором хранятся id` = ".$id); //$id - переменная, в которой передаётся id 
?>
```

Вариант 2 - проверять в цикле на нужный Вам id

```
<?
foreach ($zayav as $zayav) {
    if($zayav['Ваш столбец в котором хранятся id'] == $id){ //$id - переменная, в которой передаётся id 
        ...
    }
}
?>
```